# Setting keyword entry in opensearch.xml

Tags: firefox, opensearch

When I check the firefox settings for searchengines I can see a column for keyword
[image]

In the opensearch.xml I can define `Tags` which does not create an entry here. When I add my own opensearch, I want to also set the "Keyword". How do you do that?

My `opensearch.xml` looks like this so far and is working (I can add the search in firefox over the green plus icon in the search bar):

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>MyTitle</ShortName>
    <Description>My Description
    </Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <Tags>mytitle</Tags>
    <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">https://myexample.com/favicon.ico</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" template="https://myexample.com">
        <Param name="query" value="{searchTerms}"/>
    </Url>
    <moz:SearchForm>https://myexample.com</moz:SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

I couldn't find any references in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the keyword entry is a user-defined shortcut, you can't set it in your opensearch.xml.